# Output video with sound using open-cv python

Tags: python, opencv

i already have the function to save the video and output in the directory, the problem now is that it comes out without sound, im using open cv writer:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0);

if video.isOpened(): 
    # get vcap property 
    width  = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))  # float `width`
    height  = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))  # float `width`

output = cv2.VideoWriter('edited.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','p','4','v'), 30, (width, height))

while True:

        grabbed, frame = video.read();

        if grabbed == True:
                hh, ww = frame.shape[:2]
                w, h = (6, 6)
                result = cv2.resize(frame, (w, h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
                result_enl = cv2.resize(result, (ww, hh), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
           
                colors_ = [];
                
                for i, row in enumerate(result):
                        my_array = np.array(result[i]);
                        max_values = my_array.max(0);
                        r, g, b = (int(max_values[0]),int(max_values[1]),int(max_values[2]));
                        cx, cy = int(width/2), int(height/2)-300;
                        
                        # creating each rectangle of color
                        size = (15, 100);
                        middle_size = int(size[1]);
                        top_left = (30, cy + (i*size[1]));
                        bottom_right = (size[0], cy + (size[1] * (i+1)));
                        cv2.rectangle(frame, top_left, bottom_right, (r, g, b), -1);
                        cv2.putText(frame, str(i), (30, cy + ((i*size[1]) + 50)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (36,255,12), 2)
                
                video_output = cv2.resize(frame,(width,height));
                output.write(video_output); 
                cv2.imshow("frame", frame);
        else: 
                break;
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        
        # if the `q` key is pressed, break from the loop
        if key == ord("q"):
                break

output.release();
video.release();
```

how can i play the video with sound and outwrite it edited with sound also? using open-cv default functions it plays without sound and comes out without sound

Comment: opencv wont read or write audio, it's a computer-vision library, please dont try to abuse it to build a media player

Comment: its not a media player lol, i just building a video analizer, just want to get the main colors from the video, but some videos may have sound, so i need to save it with sound also it it has

Comment: use ffmpeg / gstreamer directly then, not opencv

Comment: gsstreamer cant do what open cv do when analyzing video lol, i edited the video already with opencv, just need a way to add the audio to it

Comment: Dont use opencv for audio, it is s computer vision library, not a video editing sdk. You can for example read the frames (video+audio) with an appropriate library and feed the read video frames to opencv for your processing.

Comment: portaudio library may help you. portaudio + opencv